# How to insert “far” and “more” in a sentence for emphasis?

Tags: sentence-construction

I want to say that things currently discussed are actually not important, and we should move on to other more important things.

I’m confused which one to select between these sentences below:

- “Actually, there are far more things that need more attention right now.” (Too much of ‘more’?)
- “Actually, there are things that far need more attention right now.” (‘Far need’? I think I never heard of that)
- “Actually, there are things that need far more attention right now.” (‘Need far more’ also sounds weird)

Strangely, even though I want to emphasise the ‘attention’ part, but the first sentence sounds the best for me. But I don’t want to emphasise on the ‘quantity’ of other things that need more attention. I want to emphasise on the attention level needed. How can I worded this sentence correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Actually, there are things that need far more attention right now.

This is perfectly fine, as is the first sentence. It doesn't sound weird at all. And as you said, it places the emphasis on the amount of attention needed rather than the number of things needing attention.

The second sentence is ungrammatical:

> Actually, there are things that far need more attention right now.

You can't split up "far" and "more."

Comment: Thanks for the response, and about the tips of not splitting far and more.